# supermatrix.h not found

Tags: python

I'm trying to [install tasmet](https://github.com/amdj/tasmet/wiki/Installation-guide) and I'm running into problems with the `python install_local.py` part.

I get the error multiple times:

```
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/include_superlu.hpp:95:12: fatal error: 
      '/supermatrix.h' file not found
  #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(ARMA_SLU_SUPERMATRIX_H)
```

I've already installed superlu-dev as listed on https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/719

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected their official instruction because Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS has newer versions of SWIG and Armadillo (no need to build them from source):

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base libsuperlu4 libsuperlu-dev \
cmake git python-numpy python-dev libarmadillo-dev swig3.0 clang
# note: for 17.10 (artful) use `libsuperlu5` instead of `libsuperlu4`

git clone --recursive https://github.com/amdj/tasmet.git
cd tasmet
python install_local.py
```

Then test it:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/$USER/bin/TaSMET
python -c "import TaSMET"
```